# Standard Viewport setting not working for Android/Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, meta-tags

My meta viewport is as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />
```

On an Android phone under Chrome my web page display is not scaled. It appears with tiny text, pics, etc. The same page is fine on my iPhone.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: `user-scalable` affects the ability to zoom on a mobile. You may want to turn that to `no` (`1` is invalid anyway). Otherwise, you'll need to update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Check out the attributes for viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes

user-scalable=1" - should also be 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: The first link gives a 404 and the second doesn't cover `viewport`, but I think you're right.